# Custom Share, Login Button for Facebook SDK iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

Im sharing image to Facebook to using Facebook SDK. problem is i dont know how to change those buttons to custom buttons. ex: if i trigger button then it shares with facebook.

here my code. this is the one Facebook give as default

```
let button : FBSDKShareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
        button.shareContent = content

        self.view.addSubview(button) // how can i trigger with my button
        button.center = self.view.center // i dont want this in center either
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way of doing this. just need to hide the button that FBSDK gives and insert following code in action button

```
button.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
```

it will Programmatically fire the SDK button if we click that UIButton

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. It's seems like FB SDK didn't consider the needs of customize the sharing button. Is anyone can confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to customize the `FBSDKLoginButton` view is add a view in the interface builder and changed its class to `FBSDKLoginButton`, then I added a subView in it then customized it in the way I want.

what happens is that the Facebook SDK will always add a subView on top on all views in the view of type `FBSDKLoginButton`, so I took an outlet of the view which has the type `FBSDKLoginButton` and in `viewDidLoad` function I added this line of code:

```
facebookLoginButton.subviews[facebookLoginButton.subviews.count-1].removeFromSuperview()
```

I think it's the same principle for the share button.